# Llamar funciones desde vistas a otro archivo EXTJS?

Tags: extjs

Estoy creando un formulario en [EXTJS 3](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/3.4.0/)  y quiero separar stores, funciones y vistas.

Me gustaría que en la vista al presionar algún evento, este llame a una funcion, pero esa funcion este en otro archivo y de esa manera se importe. Lo mismo quiero realizar con los stores.

Si bien en los stores se indica en el AJAX la ruta, no se como podría hacerlo para las funciones.

¿Como se puede usar esos archivos de esos modo (moduladamente)?
¿Mediante algun extend? ¿requires?

Answer (score 0):

En el extend agregas la ruta del controller padre asi podras ver todas las funciones que el contenga, y para hacer el llamado de las funciones solo agregas

```
this.nombreDeFuncion()
```

también puedes pasar parámetros, o también puedes declarar un Singleton y las funciones o variables se vuelven globales.